# Google and SEO services

Tags: seo, google, google-search

Are there any good and reasonably priced SEO services that work well?

Also can I pay Google to have my site at the top of searches? I was looking into Google Adsense and I am not sure if that is what I want...

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what is a reasonably price for SEO services, you can compare various offer from well-known web-agencies.

Otherwise, you can pay Google for having your website at the top or at the right of Google searches for keywords you choose ; it's called [Google Adwords](http://adwords.google.com).

[Google Adsense](http://support.google.com/adsense/?hl=en) is an other service from Google to get paid for displaying ads on your website.

Answer (score 0):

Not really and no.

You can pay people to do SEO for you. Some sell links which is frowned upon and get you penalized in Google when such activity is detected. A good SEO service is one where you are paying someone to acquire non-paid links for you and those are even been praised by Google (*I'll look the the link*). The point is that those people do not buy links but are contacting site owners to present your site and - if the like it and respond - eventually get some links out of them.

That is one half of SEO as the other is onsite SEO. Those are changes make to your site to make the website more understandable to search engines. A number of people, including myself, offer such services. Regardless, this is not a science and rules change all the time. Even worse, the rules are never specified explicitly other than major *bad* things to avoid. Results will vary depending on *so* many factors.

Paying Google does not get you in *organic* search results but it will get you on top of some searches based on the keywords you target and budget. It is effective if you have a good conversion rate and profit margin as each click costs you money and you have to eventually recover it considering the number of people who click but do not buy. To go this way, you have to go with AdWords.

Comment: Sadly there's many legit ways of buying links that Google won't punish you. I can think of 2 ways in fact, maybe it merits me making a blog post about it

Comment: @bybe - Please do and let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your site on first page of Google by using Google Adwords. But it is different from organic search. Your site name will be placed in the ads location of Google search result.

For a SEO service that works well. I think there are no guarantee that your site will be in the first page of Google (No matter how much you pay). They will only help your site more "search engine friendly".

Because Google will naturally improving their algorithm for users need. As long as your site is the one that users really need, Google likely will  raise you up on top of its search result.